# Keystore Not Recognising Certificates

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, jsse

I've been working on embedding 2 SSL Certificates into my java code and the below code doesn't generate any errors but when i try and access the API that needs these certificates i get an error. I've obviously got something wrong but after spending a significant amount of time I've not been able to solve what is wrong.

Here is the code i'm using, error below

```
    InputStream certInIssue =
            ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/SSLCerts/Certificate1.cer");
    InputStream certInRoot =
            ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/SSLCerts/Certificate.cer");

    try {
        KeyStore keystore;

        keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

        keystore.load(null, null);

        String password = "R9NNXVSqemsghmvZxkcWTfzCr3pDv5D2";

        String tempDir = "C:/Temp/";

        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(certInIssue);
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        while (bis.available() > 0) {
            java.security.cert.Certificate cert = cf.generateCertificate(bis);
            keystore.setCertificateEntry("SSLIssue", cert);
        }

        bis = new BufferedInputStream(certInRoot);
        cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        while (bis.available() > 0) {
            java.security.cert.Certificate cert = cf.generateCertificate(bis);
            keystore.setCertificateEntry("SSLRoot", cert);
        }

        certInIssue.close();
        certInRoot.close();

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempDir + "keyserverstore.keystore");
        keystore.store(out, password.toCharArray());
        out.close();

        keystore.load(new FileInputStream(tempDir + "keyserverstore.keystore"),
                            password.toCharArray());

    } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException | IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I get this exception:

```
io.joshworks.restclient.http.exceptions.RestClientException:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: What did you do with the keystore after this?

Comment: I'm trying to get a token so i can access an API. After that i guessed that when i called the code to access the website to get the token it would automatically use the keystore, i'm guessing that isn't correct?

Comment: Sigh. What did you do with the keystore after this *in your code*?

Comment: Nothing as i guessed the loaded keystore would be referrenced automatically.

Comment: You are seriously expecting some unknown piece of software to automatically load a keystore called `keyserverstore.keystore`? Or your local `KeyStore` variable to magically propagate out of its scope?